# How to get the Hour between two Dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, decimal

I want to know how to get the exact hours between two dates in SQL Server.

I have two queries, but I am not getting the time I want; can you guys help me with this problem? The first one is this:

```
SELECT p.Id, p.FechaInicio, p.FechaFin, 
       DATEDIFF(MINUTE, p.FechaInicio, p.FechaFin) / 60 AS 'Duracion' 
FROM Programaciones p
INNER JOIN Usuarios u ON u.Id = p.Programacion_Usuario
WHERE u.Nombre = 'User 1'
ORDER BY p.FechaCreacion DESC
```

This is the result:

[image]

And the second one is this:

```
SELECT p.Id, p.FechaInicio, p.FechaFin, 
       DATEDIFF(MINUTE, p.FechaInicio, p.FechaFin) / 60.0 as 'Duracion' 
FROM Programaciones p
INNER JOIN Usuarios u ON u.Id = p.Programacion_Usuario
WHERE u.Nombre = 'User 1'
ORDER BY p.FechaCreacion DESC
```

result:

[image]

How can I transform 0.500000 to 0.5?

Thanks if you can help me. Have a good day.

Comment: what RDBMS?  Round seems like it would work or format...  should all values for duration be 999.9?  What's the min max range and display value desired for the COLUMN not just one row?  should the output be numeric or text? (or does it mattter?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast your number as `DECIMAL()` to define how many decimal places you want to preserve:

```
CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, p.FechaInicio, p.FechaFin) / 60.0 AS DECIMAL(5,1)) as 'Duracion' from Programaciones
```

The first parameter in `DECIMAL()` is the number of digits in total, the second is how many digits after the decimal point, in the case above, 5 digits total, 1 after the decimal point.

You could also wrap it in `ROUND()`.